# Open Source Silverlight Control Projects on Codeplex?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, codeplex

Are there any good open source Silverlight projects that deal with a control gallery? I am looking for some cool controls (e.g., chart controls, line controls, buttons, etc. built in Silverlight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Blacklight](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/), and [here](http://www.codeplex.com/blacklight).

Answer (score 2):

[Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

It is not open source project but awesome controls arr available from Component One and I have used them to experienced ease of use for them.